# How to handle a interview where my current employer will sabotage my reputation?

Tags: interviewing, background-check, bullying, first-job, belgium

When interviewing, how should I handle a situation where my current employer will totally destroy my reputation and thus sabotage my chances of getting a future job?

I also have Autism Spectrum Disorder and Bipolar type 2, which complicates the situation. I work in a factory. This is my first job as a programmer/laborer. Concerning the programming part, I was left on my own. My productivity was slow, because I wasn't experienced and the project assignment were just very big. However, my boss 'spins' the truth the way he wants. Overall, his behaviour is unreasonable. My treatment seems to be part of a plan to reduce R&D efforts drastically in the company.

My boss talked a year ago to me. He was really mad at me. One of the things he literally said was: "When you will look for another job, surely you do know that they will do a background check and that will lead to our company?"

An ex co-worker was in a very similar situation. He wanted to leave his job. He was initially accepted at another company during an interview. However, when that company did a background check, my boss told them that my co-worker was 'crazy and totally freaking out', which led to the cancellation of the job offer.

So he has done this treatment already with an ex co-worker. Surely I can expect the same treatment.

When interviewing, how should I go about this issue with my current employer?

I know that a common rule during interview is "don't say bad things about your past employers", but in this case I have a hard time grasping how I should handle this situation as professionally as possible.
I have made a nearly complete transcript of what my boss told me, just after that conversation, and it's totally not acceptable what he said.

Comment: Where do you live? In many countries, badmouthing ex-employees would be illegal.

Comment: I live in Belgium.

Comment: @GastonLagaffe, I am not familiar with the labour law in Belgium. However, can you try to talk to a labour law lawyer to see if the lawyer can contact your current boss and company and stop them from giving negative references to the companies that interview you ?

Comment: Does your company have some sort of HR team? Can you get a written employment history from them instead?

Comment: @GregoryCurrie My company has an HR team of exactly 1 person. And that person is going to leave the company soon as well. I can try.

Comment: @gnat This answers my question, apart from the legal aspect, which is specific to Belgium. But I should look contact a labour law lawyer by myself.

Comment: Could you explain ASD for those who don't know?

Comment: Keep in mind that you will talk to your prospective new employer before your prospective new employer will check references.  Tell them upfront that your boss threatens employees with bad references to scare them to not leave and that you've seen him do it to others, so you don't expect a good reference; but, you worked there for quite some time, so obviously they were happy with your work or they would have fired you.